# Is emptiness of the intersection of the languages of two TMs decidable?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, undecidability

Let

$\qquad \mathrm{DISJOINT} = \{ \langle M_1,M_2 \rangle : M_1, M_2 \text{ are TMs and } L(M_1) \cap L(M_2) = \emptyset\}$.

How do I know if this language is decidable or not? And How do I prove my answer?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Are you familiar with the concept of reductions?

Comment: I don't know where to start. Is it undecidable ?

Comment: @Altaïr that's what you're trying to prove. Modify your question to show the precise steps you have taken to solve the problem, and where are you getting stuck.

Comment: @Ryan I don't know how to start. I can't think of something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a decider $R$ for DISJOINT, you could use this to make a decider D for $E_\text{TM} = \{\langle M\rangle\mid L(M)=\emptyset\}$ as follows:

```
D(<M>) =
   return R(<M>, <A>)
```

where $A$ was a TM, selected in such a way that $\langle M\rangle\in E_\text{TM}$ if and only if $(\langle M\rangle, \langle A\rangle)\in\text{ DISJOINT}$. All that's left for you is to find the $A$ and show that it satisfies the needed conditions. (There are a couple of ways to make this choice.)

Comment: Another possibility is to choose $M_1 = M_2$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus That's what I had in mind, along with the other choice. Didn't want to give it all away.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If DISJOINT were decidable then even the special case in which $M_1$ is some fixed machine which accepts all inputs is decidable. This is the language $\{ \langle M \rangle : L(M) = \emptyset \}$, which you might be more familiar with.

Comment: I am confused. I don't understand. I think it's undecidable. Are you suggesting to Reduce $E_{TM}$ to $DISJOINT$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's another way of putting it.

Comment: Are we gonna assume that DISJOINT is decidable and use that assumption to show that $E_{TM}$ IS decidable ?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: So we assume we have a TM R that decides DISJOINT then we use R to construct TM S that decides $E_{TM}$ then we use R as subroutine to construct S. I just don't know how to write the algorithm.

Comment: It's gonna be something like proving $HALT_{TM}$ in Sipser's book. I just can't figure out what exactly to write

Comment: I've given you enough hints. I suggest you spend a few hours trying to completing the proof, and if you're still stuck, you can ask a new question about it.

Comment: @RickDecker I can't find a reduction. Can you give me more hints ? I am trying to use R that decides DISJOINT as subroutine to construct TM S that decides $E_{TM}$ and write algorithm.(reduction)

Comment: See my expansion on the hints you've been given. The missing parts are up to you to fill in.

Comment: @Altaïr This is a discussion you should have with a fellow student and/or teacher in front of board, on on some website. (As opposed to what Yuval advises, please bring your attempts and specific questions back to *this* question by editing it.)